# iPhone App Delete Photos

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to delete photos within an iPhone Application? My application takes pictures and puts them in the Saved folder on the iPhone. I want to allow the user to delete these pictures throught the application as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apple does not provide api's for deleting photos from the camera roll.  However, if your application takes or edits pictures you could give the user the option to discard or save before the photo is committed to the saved photos.  But in short, once the photo is committed to saved photos, it cannot be deleted.